# How to make a parse.com log out button to take me to another activity which lets me either log in or sign up?

Tags: java, android, button, parse-platform, fragment

i have an activity that lets me sign up or simply log in, when the user has been logged in, four fragments, which can be navigated through scrollable tabs  are displayed, the last fragment has a log out button, i need that log out button to 1)log out directly from parse.com and 2)get the user to the activity where they can sign up or sign in.

This is the code that i have so far

THIS IS THE SIGN IN OR SIGN UP ACTIVITY

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.signup_or_login);

    // Log in button click handler
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.login)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Starts an intent of the log in activity
            startActivity(new Intent(SignUpOrLogInActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
        }
    });

    // Sign up button click handler
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.signup)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Starts an intent for the sign up activity
            startActivity(new Intent(SignUpOrLogInActivity.this, SignUpActivity.class));
        }
    });
}
```

THIS IS THE SET UP FRAGMENT WHERE THE LOG OUT BUTTON IS LOCATED

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.setup_fragment,container,false);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        logout = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.logout_button);

        // Logout Button Click Listener
        logout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Logout current user
                ParseUser.logOut();
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), SignUpOrLogInActivity.class));

            }

        });

    }
}
```

The problems are 1)that when i run the app, it first starts at the scrollable tabs (the fragments) and not at the sign in or sign up activity and 2)when i go to the set up fragment where the log out button is located the app crashes and a message is displayed saying "unfortunately your app has stopped.

HERE IS THE MANIFEST

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:name=".ParseStarter">
    <activity
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".DispatchActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".SignUpActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".SignUpOrLogInActivity" />
</application>
```

HERE IS THE LOGCAT

```
Process: com.sebasdeldihotmail.mediocre, PID: 1863
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
            at com.sebasdeldihotmail.mediocre.Setup.onCreate(Setup.java:35)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1763)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:913)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1489)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:486)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1073)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:249)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:549)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
12-14 00:26:52.791    1863-1863/com.sebasdeldihotmail.mediocre I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 1863 SIG: 9
```

AND HERE IS THE DISPATCH ACTIVITY CLASS

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.setup_fragment,container,false);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    logout = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.logout_button);

    // Logout Button Click Listener
    logout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Logout current user
            ParseUser.logOut();
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), SignUpOrLogInActivity.class));

        }

    });

}
```

THANKS FOR TAKING THE TIME FOR READING THIS I REALLY APPRECIATE IT.

Comment: You have a Activity 'SignUpOrLogInActivity' that contains two button "log in" and "sign up" after log in or sign up control goes to another activity that contains four tab bar.. and last one has a log out button. after click this button control again goes to 'SignUpOrLogInActivity' this activity... am i right .... now you can post you logcat...

Comment: yes sir, you are right! thats exactly what i wanna do !

Comment: post your logcat "full error message" please

Comment: what is DispatchActivity ? is it tab container activity ... ?

Comment: DispatchActivity is a class that i made to see if there is a logged user or not, let me put the code :)

Comment: I just put the code of the DispatchActivity on the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For  problem 1: you wrote this in you manifest file

```
<activity android:name=".DispatchActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity android:name=".LoginActivity" />
<activity android:name=".SignUpActivity" />
<activity android:name=".SignUpOrLogInActivity" />
```

now change it

```
<activity android:name=".SignUpOrLogInActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity android:name=".LoginActivity" />
<activity android:name=".SignUpActivity" />
```

For problem 2:
now look your logout button object ... its actually null .. you inflate a layout in `onCreateView`.. so you need to make a button object that associated this view .. so do this inside `onCreateView()` method

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.setup_fragment,container,false);
    Button logout = (Button)root.findViewById(R.id.logout_button);
    logout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Logout current user
            ParseUser.logOut();
            startActivity(new Intent((ParentActivity)getActivity(), SignUpOrLogInActivity.class));

        }

    });
  return root;
}
```

Hope it works ... if face any problem .. just comment it... Thank you

Comment: So in that case what should i return for the onCreateView method?